# How do I profile `paster serve`'s startup time?

Tags: python, performance, profiling, paster

Python's `paster serve app.ini` is taking longer than I would like to be ready for the first request.

I know how to profile requests with middleware, but how do I profile the initialization time? I would like it to not fork a thread pool and quit as soon as it is ready to serve so the time after it's ready doesn't show up in the profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I almost always use `paster serve --reload ...` during development. That command executes itself as a subprocess (it executes its own script using the `subprocess` module, not `fork()`).

The subprocess polls for source code changes, quits when it detects a change, and gets restarted by the parent `paster serve --reload`.

That's to say if you're going to profile `paster serve` itself, omit the `--reload` argument. Profiling individual requests with middleware should work fine either way.

My particular problem was that `pkg_resources` takes an amount of time proportional to all installed packages when it is first invoked. I solved it by rebuilding my virtualenv without unnecessary packages.

Answer (score 1):

In general your methodology could be to do timing blocks around the sections of code and then issue logging statements.  As far as the shutdown after init, I'm not familiar with the specifics of what you're using.

Edit:  I've used this middleware to help me find performance sinkholes.  It's currently a werkzeug middleware, you may be able to adapt it for you usage.  Hope it helps

```
import re
re_profile = re.compile(ur'(^|&|\?)prof($|=|&)')
class ProfilerMiddleware(BaseProcessor):
    def process_runner(self, runner, environ):
        self.profiler = None
        if (environ['REMOTE_ADDR'] in settings_static.internal_ips or settings_static.local_server) and re_profile.match(environ['QUERY_STRING']):
            self.profiler = cProfile.Profile()
            def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
                return self.profiler.runcall(runner, *args, **kwargs)
            return wrap

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if self.profiler:
            self.profiler.create_stats()
            out = StringIO.StringIO()
            old_stdout, sys.stdout = sys.stdout, out
            #from dozer.profile import buildtree, write_dot_graph
            #write_dot_graph(self.profiler.getstats(), buildtree(self.profiler.getstats()), "/tmp/output.gv")
            self.profiler.print_stats(1)
            sys.stdout = old_stdout
            response.response = [u'<pre>%s</pre>' % to_unicode(out.getvalue())]
            response.content_type = 'text/html'
```

Comment: I'm already running `paster` with the profiler which tells me which methods took the most time, but the output isn't very helpful yet. I'm guessing that's because it spawns worker processes and the profiler doesn't profile those in the same way.

Comment: The code I posted above seems to work pretty well in a similar forked environment, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you'd profile it - I doubt you get to much hints to optimize.

We use Paster inside a mod_wsgi setup, and to mitigate the startup time so that the user doesn't suffer from it, and make sure that e.g. toscawidgets are set up properly, we do this:

```
app = paste.fixture.TestApp(application)
# TODO-dir: FIXME, must go away!
try:
    app.get("/")
except:
    pass
```

Here application is of course the initialized/loaded paster app.